# Odoo v8: How to include project name in task notification message?

Tags: task, project-management, messaging, odoo-8

In the task notification messages (eg. "Stage changed...") I would like to include the Project name or, even better, a link to the Project or Analytic Account.

Could anybody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by overriding mail.thread message_track method.